# Obfuscate object without unsafe call of an any typed value

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have this function that obfuscates every attribute of an object that is included in `SENSITIVE_FIELDS`:

```
// lib/obfuscator.ts

const SENSITIVE_FIELDS: string[] = ["password", "socialSecurityNumber", "creditCardNumber"];



export default function obfuscate<T>(obj: T, sensitiveAttributes: string[] = SENSITIVE_FIELDS): T {
    const result: Partial<T> = {};

    for (const key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            const value = obj[key as keyof T];

            if (sensitiveAttributes.includes(key) && typeof value === "string") {
                result[key as keyof T] = "*****" as unknown as T[keyof T];
            } else if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
                result[key as keyof T] = obfuscate(value as Record<string, unknown>, sensitiveAttributes) as T[keyof T];
            } else {
                result[key as keyof T] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    return result as T;
}
```

And I call it like

```
const obfuscatedData = obfuscate<LogInRequest>(dataUser, ["password"]) as LogInRequest;
```

But I'm getting "Unsafe call of an `any` typed value." ESLint error.
This is my eslint config:

*.eslint.cjs*

```
/* eslint-env node */
module.exports = {
  extends: ['eslint:recommended','plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json', 
  },
  root: true, 
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-enum-comparison": 0,
  }
};
```

I've tried everything but still no good results.

I even tried returning a simple string but that's not the problem.
I also tried explicit generics declaration. Still no good.